# Backport Ubuntu 20 theme and icons to Ubuntu 16

Tags: 16.04, unity, icons, themes, 20.04

Is there a way to have a Ubuntu 20 look and feel on previous versions (such as 16-th LTS)? I've been searching for a theme that nails the flat and modern Ambience theme, but with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyways, After switching  to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS there is a possibility to install **communitheme** - it looks just like Ubuntu 20!

`sudo snap install communitheme`, then Logout and select **Ubuntu with communitheme snap** on the login screen.

Taken from here: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-communitheme-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux

Answer (score 1):

Standart theme of Ubuntu 16.04 called **Ambiance**.
I have found similar theme here: https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1398295/

1. Download *Ambiance.zip*
2. Unpack it to **/usr/share/themes/** folder.
3. Download and run `gnome-tweaks` tool
4. Select **Appearance/Themes/Applications: Ambiance**